# How can I show text from a div tag in an alert in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have a div tag that I wish to read the text from and show it in an alert/messagebox from Selenium IDE.  Here's the code:

```
<div class="floatRinline">$120.67</div>
```

I would like to show the value of $120.67 in an alert box while executing my Selenium IDE script

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? This seems like a really basic question that you could google and find an answer to yourself.

Comment: I know how to do this in java and you are correct, it is a simple thing.  There are no results on google, at least in my country that point me in the right direction.  I have tried a number of things, although they all give a Selenium IDE error.  I certainly wouldn't have posted a question here if there was a simple solution, at least one that I can't find.  Have you tried?  So please people, don't -1 a post just because it seems as if it has a simple answer if you haven't done it yourself!

Comment: Hi Jeff, nice to hear from you.  My problem wasn't with mapping the field, I had successfully used xPath, it was with generating the alert box.  The Selenium IDE is a plug in for Firefox that has limited abilities.  I was trying to save some time with the IDE but have since returned to java and the Selenium WebDriver which gives me all the functionality I need.  Just a note about Googling, each country will give results differently and I'm not stateside at the moment.  See you around.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store the value before you can display it in a alertbox.
    command = storeText
    Target = div.floatRinline
    value = varibaleName

Then you can display the variable that was just stored in an alertbox using javascript and the getEval command.
    command = getEval
    Target = alert("${varibaleName}")
The reason why you can't just use runscript is because it does not evaluate the stored variable.

Comment: Hi Joe, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please edit your answer to explain how this answers the question, and what the code does? Code only answers are discouraged here. Thank you!